# Set "To:" field as first responder in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, messageui

Does anyone have any ideas on the right way to do this? There is one answer to a similar question on here, but it's so convoluted, I can't imagine it being right. There has to be an easier way to just show the keyboard when this modal view pops up. right?

Answer (score 7):

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:@"Mail subject"];
[picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email@email.com",nil]];
```

Comment: I think he wants the keyboard set to the 'To:' Field when mail composer is shown, not pre-populate the field.

Comment: That's right. I want the keyboard to show like it does in ReederApp